# MVC 4 problems w Global.asax in IIS //Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an MVC application. I am trying to publish it in IIS.

The app is throwing this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. 
Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyAppMVC.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyAppMVC.MvcApplication" 
Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

I did already the basic clean, rebuild. But problem continue. Also, the global.asax file exists in the IIS folder.

I checked already that my Global.asax.cs is inheriting form HttpAplication like this MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication. Also, I configured the right .NET version in my App Pool.

I checked the event log:

```
   <Data>Could not load type 'MyAppMVC.MvcApplication'. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() 
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) 
Could not load type 'MyAppMVC.MvcApplication'. 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() Could not load type 'MyAppMVC.MvcApplication'. 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) 
Could not load type 'MyAppMVC.MvcApplication'. 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)</Dat
```

a>

Anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: Do you have a `bin` folder which contains your `MyAppMVC.dll`?

Comment: On the application pool, do you have integrated pipeline enabled ? If you have classic, that is the problem.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin: Yes, I have that dll in my bin folder.

Comment: @Cosmin In the app pool I set the managed pipeline mode like integrated.

Comment: Is the application working locally ? Also, you can check if you have additional information in Windows Event Log (look for messages of ASP.NET)

Comment: @Cosmin The app is published in a server. Right now, I browse it in that server.

Comment: @Cosmin I put in the question what I found in the event log

Comment: One common reason for this kind of problems is if you rename the project file after it was created. In your Gobal.asax.CS file, the class MvcApplication is inside the namespace MyAppMVC ?

Comment: @Cosmin I didnt rename that files. The weird of this error is that the app worked. But something happened and it starts to crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not load type \[Namespace\].Global" causing me grief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief)