# csc.exe error in MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

The Asp.net web application I am working on (seemingly)randomly started to error this morning. I have tried all day to fix it but have not managed to make any progress.

The error show within visual studio is as follows.

```
"csc.exe" exited with code -532462766.  ReportLogProject".
```

When I debug, the error shown in the browser is

```
"Could not load type 'ReportLogProject.Global'."

"<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
Inherits="ReportLogProject.Global" Language="C#" %>"
```

I have tried rebuilding, re-installing compiler packages etc. but nothing has worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit. Global.asax.cs and Globsal.asac code added below.

```
namespace ReportLogProject
{
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
 }
}
```

Global Asax:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ReportLogProject.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without some code.  Add your global.asax and global.asax.cs files to the question.

Comment: -532462766 = 0xE0434352. This error code may be misleading though, please check Build Configuration & related assemblies first. Also attach your Global.asax.cs code & follow the steps provided there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief.

Comment: I have been through countless threads discussing the cannot load type issue and none of the suggestions have fixed it.