# Could not loade type "xx.xx" in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: Global.asax error]

I'm frequently getting this error, I tried changing Codebehind to CodeFile in Global.asax file, but not luck. Any help will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not load type \[Namespace\].Global" causing me grief](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005747/could-not-load-type-namespace-global-causing-me-grief)

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to project properties > build > Output Path = bin\ (value to output path to 'bin\'). Clean, rebuild and enjoy.